# Where do you physically mail the I-485 for concurrent filings?

Tags: usa, immigration, uscis, concurrent-i130-i485

The instructions on the webpage do not have the address for concurrent mailing

- https://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-processes-and-procedures/concurrent-filing-of-form-i-485

What address do I send this to?

Answer (score 1):

## There is not one address

The instructions are on this page [Direct Filing Addresses for Form I-485, Application to Register Permanent Residence or Adjust Status](https://www.uscis.gov/forms/all-forms/direct-filing-addresses-for-form-i-485-application-to-register-permanent-residence-or-adjust-status)
, specifically here,

> - A spouse, parent, or unmarried son or daughter (under age 21) of a U.S. citizen with either an approved Form I-130 or you are filing Form I-485 together with Form I-130;
>
> Go to our [USCIS Lockbox Filing Locations Chart for Certain Family-Based Forms page for the filing address based on where you live.](https://www.uscis.gov/uscis-lockbox-filing-locations-chart-for-certain-family-based-forms)